# if $a_1,a_2,a_3,..$.Is a geometric sequence,

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $a_1,a_2,a_3,..$.Is a geometric sequence,

$$a_1+a_2+a_3=63$$

$$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}=\frac{12}{48}$$

$$a_2=?$$

my tried:$$×a_1×a_2×a_3\to {a_2×a_3}+a_1×a_2+a_1×a_3=\frac{12}{48}×a_1×a_2×a_3$$

$$(a_2)^2=a_1×a_3$$

:(

Comment: Why not just $\frac 14$ instead of $\frac {12}{48}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's a geometric sequence, we have $(a_2)^2=a_1 a_3$

Now

$$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}=\frac{a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_3}{a_1 a_2 a_3 } = \frac{a_2 (a_1 + a_2+a_3)}{a_2^3}$$

You should be able to go on from here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_2=a$ and let $r=$ common ratio of GP.

$$\begin{align}
a\left(\frac 1r+1+r\right)&=63\qquad\cdots (1)\\
\frac 1a\left(r+1+\frac 1r\right)&=\frac 14\qquad\cdots(2)\\
(1)\div (2):\hspace{5cm}\\
a^2&=7\cdot 9\cdot 4\\
a_2=a&=\color{red}{6\sqrt{7}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

A few things to keep in mind

$a_n = r a_{n-1}\\
a_n = r^n a_0$

I like to start from $0.$

$\frac {1}{a_n}$ is also a geometric series with growth rate $\frac 1r$

the sum of a geometric series:

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n} a_0 r^i = \frac {a_0(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$

With that between the two equations you should be able to find $a_0$ and $r$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac{a_2}{a_1}=\dfrac{a_3}{a_2}=d$(say)

$$63=a_1(1+d+d^2)\  \ \ \ (1)$$

$$\dfrac{12}{48}=\dfrac1{a_1}\dfrac{1+d+d^2}{d^2}\  \ \ \ (2)$$

Divide $(1)$ by $(2)$